# Store the output of a function into a variable

Tags: python, function

I have the following function that returns data:

```
def get_comments():
 for i in data:
  comment_data = i['comments']
  for z in comment_data:
   comments = comment_data['data']
   for j in comments:
    comment = j['message']
    print(comment)
```

I would like to save the output of this function to a variable. I'm using print instead of return (in the function get_comments) since, return only returns the final row of my data. This is what i have tried to account for that:

```
def hypothetical(x):
return x

z = hypothetical(get_comments())
print(z)
```

However the output of the variable z is "None".

When i try some other value(i.e.):

```
 z = hypothetical(5)
 print(z)
```

z is equal to 5 of course.
Thanks

Comment: If `print()` prints the data you want, then `return` will return that same data

Comment: Hi Tom, it does not, it only returns the last row of my data

Comment: Ah I think I understand you then. Instead of `print`ing each line, you need to add it to a different data structure (such as a list) and return the whole list at the end of `get_comments()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of printing each line, you need to add it to a different data structure (such as a list) and return the whole list at the end of `get_comments()`.

For example:

```
def get_comments():
  to_return = []
  for i in data:
    comment_data = i['comments']
    for z in comment_data:
      comments = comment_data['data']
      for j in comments:
        comment = j['message']
        to_return.append(comment)
  return to_return
```

---

If you want to get a bit more advanced, you can instead create a `generator` using `yield`:

```
def get_comments():
  for i in data:
    comment_data = i['comments']
    for z in comment_data:
      comments = comment_data['data']
      for j in comments:
        comment = j['message']
        yield comment
```

Then you can iterate over `get_comments()` and it will go back into the generator each time to get the next comment. Or you could simply cast the generator into a list with `list(get_comments())` in order to get back to your desired list of comments.

Refer to [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/6732358) for more about `yield` and generators.